# Rails Avoid Duplicate Records on Join Table has_many to has_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, orm

We have the regular model of a user (user.rb):

Model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :clientes,         through: :clientes_users
end
```

And a simple model for clients (cliente.rb):

Model:

```
class Cliente < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :clientes_users
    has_many :users,            through: :clientes_users
end
```

We created the join table (many to many) (clientes_user.rb):

```
class ClientesUser < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :cliente
    belongs_to :user
end
```

When we create the user we use:

```
@user = User.new(
            :email => params[:email],
            :access_level => params[:access_level],
            :password => params[:password_first],
            :password_confirmation => params[:password_confirmation]
        )
        params[:cliente_id].each do |cliente|
            @user.clientes_users.build(
              :cliente => Cliente.find(cliente)
            )
        end
        @user.save
```

All works fine and our table store the data:

[image]

But when we update the relations, the record dupliate the entries.

[image]

What's the best way to avoid that behavior, if the relations doesn't exist insert the data but if exist just ignore

Comment: Can you show us your update action? You only pasted the create action, and if I am not mistaken, create is not the problem you are asking about.

Comment: Hi, sorry you are right
`@user = User.find(8)
        @user.clientes_users.build(
            :cliente => Cliente.find(6)
        )
        @user.save`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Defining a `has_many` association also gives you setters and getters. `@user` should have methods `cliente_ids` and `clientes_ids=`, that can be used for assignment. You can do the following:

```
@user = User.create!(
  email: params[:email],
  access_level: params[:access_level],
  password: params[:password_first],
  password_confirmation: params[:password_confirmation],
  cliente_ids: params[:cliente_id]
)
```

Also note that the mismatches between `password` and `password_first`, as well as between `cliente_ids` and `cliente_id` are misleading, it would be nice to have the same name in both cases.

When param names are the same as the model attributes, you can then go one step further and do that:

```
@user = User.create!(user_params)

def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:email, :access_level, :password, :password_confirmation, :cliente_ids)
end
```

Remove `require(:user)` if the controller params are not scoped under the key `user`, even though they probably should.

Hope this helped.

Comment: The problem isn't how is called is how can i avoid the duplicates when the data will insert.